# Dotnet build doesn't work with newcsproj and PackageReference

Tags: c#, .net

Reproduce steps:

1. Open Visual Studio 2017, create new class library project, `.NET 4.6.1`.
2. Add reference to `Newtonsoft.Json` with Nuget Package Manager.
3. Build project successfully with `VS2017`.
4. Open command line and run `dotnet build` from project directory.

It gives the following error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

dotnet version:
[image]

Any ideas how to get rid of this error?

Edit:
Before running dotnet restore:

[image]

After running dotnet restore

[image]

Edit with files:
 ClassLibrary1.csproj

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{42A41D81-0A26-4D79-935E-6002BFAD37EB}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>ClassLibrary1</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>ClassLibrary1</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <Version>9.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Class1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        [JsonProperty]
        public string asd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as text rather than as a screenshot. It sounds like you haven't run `dotnet restore`...

Comment: @JonSkeet Hey Jon. Actually I have tried to do that. Look at edit please. Regarding the minimal example, I gave you  the repro. Screenshot is just to display the version.

Comment: Rather than tell us how you did it, please just show us the files so that we can copy/paste/build.

Comment: I've just tried it in Visual Studio, and it was fine.

Comment: what files? You mean solution files?

Comment: No, the project file and the C# file. So that we can copy/paste both, run `dotnet restore` and then `dotnet build`. It *looks* like your project file simply didn't get saved somehow.

Comment: @JonSkeet See edit please

Comment: Ah, I see the problem - you're not using the new csproj format. You're using the old one. You want the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template when creating the project.

Comment: PackageReference is a part of new csproj, isn't it? Visual Studio created this csproj for me. I want the class library with .NET Framework not .NET core.

Comment: No, the fact that you've got `<Project ToolsVersion="...">` instead of `Project Sdk="...">` shows it's the old style. You can still target the desktop framework from the new style though - see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the "old style" msbuild project, which won't work with the `dotnet` CLI.

Replace your whole project file with:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now it will be compatible with the `dotnet` CLI, and all should be well.

Comment: PackageReference is a part of new csproj, isn't it? Visual Studio created this csproj for me when I created Class Library (.NET Framework) project. I have selected in Visual Studio settings to use PackageReference by default.

Comment: @MistyK: No, this is definitely the old style of csproj, even if it now supports PackageReference. You want "Class Library (.NET Core)" if you want to use the .NET Core *SDK*, even if you make it target net461 (as per my example).

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. So creating .NET Core class library project doesn't necessarily mean it's built on top of .NET core because I still can select .NET framework. I was pretty sure it's only the case for ASP.NET Core project. Cool thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To reference a library on the command line you need to use the /r: compiler option.
For example run `csc /r:Path_to_your_DLL /t:Path_to_your_.cs_files`

According to [this microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/reference-compiler-option), Visual studio seems to do the work of including all the libraries automatically when you use nuget inside visual studio, but since you are trying to build using command line, you have to manually reference all the libraries yourself.
[image]

Comment: I'm referencing it through nuget package manager, why would I do it manually in the command line?

Comment: @MistyK Updated answer